# How to get WMS layer feature attribute name

Tags: postgis, openlayers-2, openlayers

Hereby i have included my WMS layer displaying code.I referred many sites i can't able to get WMS getfeature info.Please anyone help me how to get WMS layer feature info give source code please

    
    WMS - GetFeature

```
    var osm, map, state_boundary;
    var state_code;
    var vectorLayer, vectorSource, featureRequest;

        // set up the map
        osm = new ol.layer.Tile({     // basemap layer
            title: 'OSM',
            type: 'base',
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
        });
        state_boundary = new ol.layer.Image({ 
            title: 'india',
            source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
            url: 'http://localhost/geoserver/workspace/wms?',
                params: { 'LAYERS': 'workspace:IndiaState' },
                serverType: 'geoserver'
            })
        });

        map = new ol.Map({
            layers: [osm, state_boundary],
            target: 'map',
            view: new ol.View({
                center: ol.proj.transform([78.188860, 23.176633], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
                zoom: 5
            })
        });
</script>
```